# Python "callable" attribute (pseudo-property)

Tags: python, properties

In python, I can alter the state of an instance by directly assigning to attributes, or by making method calls which alter the state of the attributes:

```
foo.thing = 'baz'
```

or:

```
foo.thing('baz')
```

Is there a nice way to create a class which would accept both of the above forms which scales to large numbers of attributes that behave this way?  (Shortly, I'll show an example of an implementation that I don't particularly like.)  If you're thinking that this is a stupid API, let me know, but perhaps a more concrete example is in order.  Say I have a `Document` class.  `Document` could have an attribute `title`.  However, `title` may want to have some state as well (font,fontsize,justification,...), but the average user might be happy enough just setting the title to a string and being done with it ...

One way to accomplish this would be to:

```
class Title(object):
     def __init__(self,text,font='times',size=12):
         self.text = text
         self.font = font
         self.size = size
     def __call__(self,*text,**kwargs):
         if(text):
             self.text = text[0]
         for k,v in kwargs.items():
             setattr(self,k,v)
     def __str__(self):
         return '<title font={font}, size={size}>{text}</title>'.format(text=self.text,size=self.size,font=self.font)

class Document(object):
     _special_attr = set(['title'])
     def __setattr__(self,k,v):
         if k in self._special_attr and hasattr(self,k):
             getattr(self,k)(v)
         else:
             object.__setattr__(self,k,v)

     def __init__(self,text="",title=""):
         self.title = Title(title)
         self.text = text

     def __str__(self):
         return str(self.title)+'<body>'+self.text+'</body>'
```

Now I can use this as follows:

```
doc = Document()
doc.title = "Hello World"
print (str(doc))
doc.title("Goodbye World",font="Helvetica")
print (str(doc))
```

This implementation seems a little messy though (with `__special_attr`).  Maybe that's because this is a messed up API.  I'm not sure.  **Is there a better way to do this?**  Or did I leave the beaten path a little too far on this one?

*I realize I could use `@property` for this as well, but that wouldn't scale well at all if I had more than just one attribute which is to behave this way -- I'd need to write a getter and setter for each, yuck*.

Comment: Also note that my actual use case does not involve a markup language, I just used this as an example that would be familiar to a larger audience.  (please don't suggest I use `elementtree` or `xml.favorite.parser` ... )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bit harder than the previous answers assume.

Any value stored in the descriptor will be shared between all instances, so it is not the right place to store per-instance data.
Also, `obj.attrib(...)` is performed in two steps:

```
tmp = obj.attrib
tmp(...)
```

Python doesn't *know* in advance that the second step will follow, so you always have to return something that is callable and has a reference to its *parent* object.

In the following example that reference is implied in the `set` argument:

```
class CallableString(str):
    def __new__(class_, set, value):
        inst = str.__new__(class_, value)
        inst._set = set
        return inst
    def __call__(self, value):
        self._set(value)

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._attrib = "foo"
    def get_attrib(self):
        return CallableString(self.set_attrib, self._attrib)
    def set_attrib(self, value):
        try:
            value = value._value
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        self._attrib = value
    attrib = property(get_attrib, set_attrib)

a = A()
print a.attrib
a.attrib = "bar"
print a.attrib
a.attrib("baz")
print a.attrib
```

In short: what you want cannot be done transparently. You'll write better Python code if you don't insist hacking around this limitation

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid having to use [`@property`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) on potentially *hundreds* of attributes by simply creating a [descriptor class](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html) that follows the appropriate rules:

```
# Warning: Untested code ahead
class DocAttribute(object):
    tag_str = "<{tag}{attrs}>{text}</{tag}>"

    def __init__(self, tag_name, default_attrs=None):
        self._tag_name = tag_name
        self._attrs = default_attrs if default_attrs is not None else {}

    def __call__(self, *text, **attrs):
        self._text = "".join(text)
        self._attrs.update(attrs)
        return self

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        return self

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self._text = value

    def __str__(self):
        # Attrs left as an exercise for the reader
        return self.tag_str.format(tag=self._tag_name, text=self._text)
```

Then you can use `Document`'s `__setattr__` method to add a descriptor based on this class if it is in a white list of approved names (or not in a black list of forbidden ones, depending on your domain):

```
class Document(object):
    # prelude
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if self.is_allowed(name):  # Again, left as an exercise for the reader
            object.__setattr__(self, name, DocAttribute(name)(value))
```

Comment: I thought that the solution might have something to do with descriptors.  *sigh*.  I guess it's time that I really dig in and try to learn how to use them.  (It's one of the corners of python I haven't spent much time exploring).

Comment: Just to be clear -- Does a descriptor behave differently from any other class if it isn't bound to an instance?

Comment: @mgilson - it doesn't differ in the slightest.  The `__get__`, `__set__` and `__delete__` methods are *only* called when you are attempting to access an attribute on a class or an instance that has these methods (and then only in certain cases).  See http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html for more information.

Comment: So an instance of `DocAttribute` is returned when we do `doc.title` - if we did `title = doc.title` we could then invoke the `__str__` or `__call__` methods of the `DocAttribute` instance without issue - it is only when `title` is attached to some other object that the descriptor methods are brought into play.